# Como importo uma biblioteca que imprima algo tirado da internet e passar mostrar ela no Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, biblioteca

Estou fazendo uma interface gráfica no Tkinter e tenho uma biblioteca que mostra a previsão do tempo (quando faço o import dessa biblioteca e rodo o programa ela já me mostra os resultados). Como eu faço para mostrar esse resultado da biblioteca em uma caixa de texto do Tk?

código da biblioteca de previsão do tempo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Autor: Fábio Berbert de Paula <fberbert@gmail.com>
Data : 27/11/2018
"""

def previsao(local=''):
    #pip install requests-html
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
    import re

    session = HTMLSession()

    url = 'https://www.google.com.br/search?q=previsao+do+tempo&oq=previsao+do+tempo&ie=UTF-8'
    if local != '':
        local = local.replace(' ', '+')
        url = url.replace('tempo', 'tempo+' + local)

    #URL resultado da busca no Google por: previsao do tempo
    r = session.get(url)

    #abaixo defino os seletores CSS de cada elemento da pagina
    #e armazeno nas devidas variaveis
    selector_city = '#wob_loc'
    city = r.html.find(selector_city, first=True).text

    selector_date = '#wob_dts'
    date = r.html.find(selector_date, first=True).text

    selector_state = '#wob_dc'
    state = r.html.find(selector_state, first=True).text

    selector_temp = '#wob_tm'
    temp = r.html.find(selector_temp, first=True).text

    #regex para limpar informacoes irrelevantes
    regex = re.compile(r'\nTemperatura.*$', re.DOTALL)
    selector_dtl = 'div.wob-dtl'
    dtl = r.html.find(selector_dtl, first=True).text
    dtl = regex.sub("", dtl)

    return("%s\n%s\t%s°C (%s)\n\n%s" %(city, date, temp, state, dtl))

#leitura da localidade (parâmetro via linha de comando)
import sys

local=''
if len(sys.argv)>0:
    sys.argv.pop(0)
    local = ' '.join(sys.argv)

print(previsao(local))
```

Comment: Depende de como está o seu código do Tkinter e como é o código dessa outra biblioteca. Sem código não temos como afirmar.

Comment: Sobre o código do Tkinter eu ainda não tenho nada praticamente feito. Mas adicionei na minha pergunta acima o código da biblioteca que quero colocar na interface do tk. Eu não estou achando um método para colocar os resultados da biblioteca na interface. O máximo que consegui fazer aparecer na interface foi o endereço da biblioteca.

Comment: Então não tem muito segredo, você tem uma função `previsao` que retorna uma *string*, basta exibí-la na interface Tk que você criar. Quando tiver algo mais concreto poderá [edit] a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 1):

Modifique a função `previsao` para retornar apenas os valores da previsão do tempo e em seguida exibi estas variáveis na propriedade `text` do widget `Label` do Tkinter.

Para testar este código salve em um `novo_arquivo.py`.

```
from tkinter import *
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
import sys

app = Tk()
app.title("Previsão do Tempo")
app.geometry("300x150+200+100")


def previsao(local=''):

    session = HTMLSession()

    url = 'https://www.google.com.br/search?q=previsao+do+tempo&oq=previsao+do+tempo&ie=UTF-8'
    if local != '':
        local = local.replace(' ', '+')
        url = url.replace('tempo', 'tempo+' + local)

    #URL resultado da busca no Google por: previsao do tempo
    r = session.get(url)

    #abaixo defino os seletores CSS de cada elemento da pagina
    #e armazeno nas devidas variaveis
    selector_city = '#wob_loc'
    city = r.html.find(selector_city, first=True).text

    selector_date = '#wob_dts'
    date = r.html.find(selector_date, first=True).text

    selector_state = '#wob_dc'
    state = r.html.find(selector_state, first=True).text

    selector_temp = '#wob_tm'
    temp = r.html.find(selector_temp, first=True).text

    #regex para limpar informacoes irrelevantes
    regex = re.compile(r'\nTemperatura.*$', re.DOTALL)
    selector_dtl = 'div.wob-dtl'
    dtl = r.html.find(selector_dtl, first=True).text
    dtl = regex.sub("", dtl)

    #return("%s\n%s\t%s°C (%s)\n\n%s" %(city, date, temp, state, dtl))
    return(city, date, temp, state, dtl)

#leitura da localidade (parâmetro via linha de comando)


local=''
if len(sys.argv)>0:
    sys.argv.pop(0)
    local = ' '.join(sys.argv)

#print(previsao(local))


city, date, temp, state, dtl = previsao(local)


Label(app,text=city).pack(side="top",padx=10)
Label(app,text=date).pack(side="top",padx=10)
Label(app,text=temp).pack(side="top",padx=10)
Label(app,text=state).pack(side="top",padx=10)
Label(app,text=dtl).pack(side="top",padx=10)

app.mainloop()
```

Saída

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]